# Resource manager vs No Resource manager

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm trying to undertsand, what's a difference between running spark job in N node cluster using `resource manager` and `without resource manager` ?

Please share

Answer (score -2):

Cluster Manager is responsible for acquiring resources on the cluster and allocating them to spark application. Refer:
[Spark architecture from docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfXWt.png)

> The cluster managers that Spark runs on provide facilities for scheduling across applications. Refer: [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-across-applications)

So without any cluster manager spark job won't be able to acquire resources on the cluster.

Comment: so you mean without resource manager will just run spark job on all nodes no matter the required resources are available or not ? If not, it will fail

Comment: Without resource manager, your job will run as in local mode i.e, only on a single node where you launch your application.

Comment: even 5 data nodes are configured ?

Comment: While submitting spark job, you have to provide --master URL. You mention here which cluster manager you want to use. Possible options are here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls
If you provide a cluster manager URL it will use the cluster manager which handles resource allocation and if you provide local it will only run on single node.

Comment: mentioning just master url wont justify that it will use resource manager only.

Comment: What do you think master url property does?

Comment: seen lots of online docs to install spark cluster and in that they are not even using resource manager but master url only. So that master url is working as default resource anager ? But some docs are there which are setting yarn explicity.